# How to run a C program which uses string.h in Ubuntu

Tags: c

My C program uses string.h.. Initially I was not able to compile it.  But then I used

```
$ gcc filename.c -E
```

Then it complied but I am not able to run it with both

```
./a.out 
./filename
```

Comment: Show the original `gcc` command you used before trying `-E`, and show the output from that command.

Answer (score 2):

The -E option to gcc invokes only the **preprocessor**.  If you want to **compile** you need to do this:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -o filename filename.c
```

The -o option specifies the name of the executable to create, the -W options enable the common compiler warnings, and -g includes debugging symbols so you can use tools such as gdb to step through the code line by line.

Comment: Compiling with `-E` is not OP’s original problem. Something is going on that is not stated in the question, so we should not expect this will solve their problem. The question ought to be clarified before it is answered.